# SSH's command "nvm install node" is'nt working because of a tar error

Tags: node.js, ssh, tar, nvm

I have installed NVM on my SSH, but the 'nvm install node' command isn't working because it's getting a tar error `tar: invalid option -- J`. How can i solve this?

complete log:

```
-bash-3.2$ nvm install node

Downloading and installing node v20.4.0...

Local cache found: ${NVM_DIR}/.cache/bin/node-v20.4.0-linux-x64/node-v20.4.0-linux-x64.tar.xz

Checksums match! Using existing downloaded archive ${NVM_DIR}/.cache/bin/node-v20.4.0-linux-x64/node-v20.4.0-linux-x64.tar.xz

tar: invalid option -- J

Try tar --help' or tar --usage' for more information.

Binary download failed, trying source.

Local cache found: ${NVM_DIR}/.cache/src/node-v20.4.0/node-v20.4.0.tar.xz

Checksums match! Using existing downloaded archive ${NVM_DIR}/.cache/src/node-v20.4.0/node-v20.4.0.tar.xz

tar: invalid option -- J

Try tar --help' or tar --usage' for more information.

nvm: install v20.4.0 failed!
```

Obs.:

1. I am using Windows 10 as SO and PuTTY to SSh access.
2. (GNU tar) 1.15.1